# PyQt5 and persistent DB with QtSql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtsql

Fairly new to PyQt5 and in setting up a sample application I ran into an issue with QtSql.  All of the examples I have found show a single class using the database connection but none show how to use the QtSql classes persistently over many different classes that require a DB connection.  Almost all of the MDI subwindows in my application require a connection to the database but when I setup the connection I get errors that the connection is "duplicate".  My question is:

If I have an MDI application with several dialogs that require a DB connection, How do I set up the database connection persistently so all my dialogs can access the database?

Comment: Are dialogs connected to several databases  or all of them to the same database?

Comment: They all connect to the same database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to connect to the same database it is not necessary that you create several connections, only one since qt manages those connections globally as indicated by the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase):

> **QSqlDatabase QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(const QString &type, const
> QString &connectionName = QLatin1String(defaultConnection))**
>
> Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver type and
> the connection name connectionName. If there already exists a database
> connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.
>
> The database connection is referred to by connectionName. The newly
> added database connection is returned.
>
> If type is not available or could not be loaded, isValid() returns
> false.
>
> If connectionName is not specified, the new connection becomes the
> default connection for the application, and subsequent calls to
> database() without the connection name argument will return the
> default connection. If a connectionName is provided here, use
> database(connectionName) to retrieve the connection.
>
> Warning: If you add a connection with the same name as an existing
> connection, the new connection replaces the old one. If you call this
> function more than once without specifying connectionName, the default
> connection will be the one replaced.

---

Example:

```
.
├── connection.py
├── main.py
└── views.p
```

**connection.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                             "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                             "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                             "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                             "to build it.\n\n"
                             "Click Cancel to exit.", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id int primary key, 
                                                     firstname VARCHAR(20), 
                                                    lastname VARCHAR(20))""")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(101, 'Danny', 'Young')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(102, 'Christine', 'Holand')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(103, 'Lars', 'Gordon')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(104, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(105, 'Maria', 'Papadopoulos')")


    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  items (id INT primary key, 
                                       imagefile INT,
                                       itemtype varchar(20),
                                       description varchar(100))""");
    query.exec_("insert into items "
               "values(0, 0, 'Qt',"
               "'Qt is a full development framework with tools designed to "
               "streamline the creation of stunning applications and  "
               "amazing user interfaces for desktop, embedded and mobile "
               "platforms.')");
    query.exec_("insert into items "
               "values(1, 1, 'Qt Quick',"
               "'Qt Quick is a collection of techniques designed to help "
               "developers create intuitive, modern-looking, and fluid "
               "user interfaces using a CSS & JavaScript like language.')");
    query.exec_("insert into items "
               "values(2, 2, 'Qt Creator',"
               "'Qt Creator is a powerful cross-platform integrated "
               "development environment (IDE), including UI design tools "
               "and on-device debugging.')");
    query.exec_("insert into items "
               "values(3, 3, 'Qt Project',"
               "'The Qt Project governs the open source development of Qt, "
               "allowing anyone wanting to contribute to join the effort "
               "through a meritocratic structure of approvers and "
               "maintainers.')");
    return True
```

**views.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql

class PersonWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PersonWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        lay.addWidget(view)
        model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        model.setTable("person")
        model.select()
        view.setModel(model)

class ItemsWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ItemsWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        lay.addWidget(view)
        model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        model.setTable("items")
        model.select()
        view.setModel(model)
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSql

from connection import createConnection
from views import PersonWidget, ItemsWidget


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)

        sub1 = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        sub1.setWidget(PersonWidget())
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sub1)
        sub1.show()

        sub2 = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        sub2.setWidget(ItemsWidget())
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sub2)
        sub2.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

In the previous example, there is the `createConnection()` method that establishes the connection and creates the tables if necessary. And the views that use the data of the database without indicating the connection and consequently use the default connection, that is, the one that was established in `createConnection()`.

Comment: I read the same thing; however, I am clueless on the implementation.  Do I create a global class that has connects to the database and returns the database handle then call that class from each dialog?

Comment: @user1532602 No, it is not necessary, to create it at the beginning, I will show an example.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for,  Thanks @eyllanesc, you have been a great resource now and in the past.  Cheers!