# How to load data from SQLite database to tableview using the sqlite3 module

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to connect to database and load data from table using Model View Controller implementation. So far all the examples connect to database using PyQt5's `QSqlDatabase` and table is created by

```
model=QSqlTabelModel()
model.setTable("table_name")
table_view=QTableView()
table_view.setModel(model)
model.select()
.....
```

I think `model` is able to select from table because it's connection to database is using `QSqlDatabase`.
I want to do the same thing but  connect to database using `sqlite3` module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt5 and persistent DB with QtSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306683/pyqt5-and-persistent-db-with-qtsql)

Comment: No, the is exactly what I have seen so far. They use QSqlDatabase, but I don't want to use it. I want to use sqlite3 instead.

Comment: Why you don't want to use it?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible and I started the project with SQLite. I dont want to change code

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to create a subclass of [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) and implement every part: model structure, database connection, data access, exception/error handling and possibly some caching; if you also need write/modification support, you must also implement data writing (and related exception/error handling), layout changes, index addition and removal, etc.

Comment: Wow! That's sound like alot, better just use `QSqlDatabase` then

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python built in driver for SQLite, but then you cannot have all of the conveniences when you want to view your table. If you are determined  to use sqlite3, then you will have to write some extra code to shove the data from your sqlite3 cursor into a QTableModel.

Since you are already committed to the PyQt5 library, you might consider learning how to use [QtSQL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html). It has the advantage of supporting many well known databases and it makes it relatively easy to view the data.

Now for an example. First create the database:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def createDB():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('test.db')
    
    # try to open the database
    if not db.open():
        raise Error("Could not open the database")


    query = QSqlQuery()

    # create a table
    query.exec_('''create table t1(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fruit TEXT, inventory int);''')

    # populate the table
    query.exec_("insert into t1 (fruit, inventory) values('banana', 3);")
    query.exec_("insert into t1 (fruit, inventory) values('mango', 10);")
    query.exec_("insert into t1 (fruit, inventory) values('cherry', 55);")
    
    db.close()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   createDB()
```

Make a viewer:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class TableViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #createDB()
        
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('test.db')
    
        # try to open the database
        if not self.db.open():
            raise Error("Could not open the database")

        # this will give you the whole table:
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)   
        self.model.setTable('t1')

        # if you don't need the whole table, you can try
        # using setSort() and setFilter() methods. if
        # those aren't satisfactory for you, you can 
        # replace the previous line with:
        #   query = QSqlQuery()
        #   query.exec_('select * from t1')
        #   self.model.setQuery(query)           

        self.model.select()

        self.tview = QTableView(self)
        self.tview.setModel(self.model)
        self.tview.resizeColumnsToContents()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tview)
        
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tv = TableViewer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what's been already discussed in the comments (which also link an answer that already answers the question): the OP didn't want to use the Qt database system because they were afraid it would be too complicate having much of the work already "done" in their existing sqlite implementation and wanted to find another way to "merge" the Qt item model with it, avoiding QtSql. Also, the documentation discourages using `setQuery` on QSqlTableModel.

Comment: @musicamente, I get it why the OP didn't want QtSQL and I realize pros and cons were discussed  in the comments. But I thought it was useful to post some example code in the event that the poster chose to look into QtSQL. Good catch on setQuery. I couldn't figure out from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setQuery) whether using this method was discouraged to hide complexity of SQL or for performance reasons. I suspect the first. I setQuery often in my own production code and haven't encountered any blatantly obvious problems.

Comment: The linked question already has some good example code, it should suffice (I marked this question as duplicated, but I retracted the vote by mistake). Yes, the documentation doesn't clarify *why* it shouldn't be used, nor warns about unexpected or unreliable behavior, which theoretically means that's is *usually* safe for general display use. Unfortunately that wouldn't be valid for complete use: `setTable()` properly "sets up" the table by preparing indexes and storing the table name, which is essential for some features like proper sorting; in fact, doing `setSortingEnabled(True)` on your ->

Comment: -> code results in having the header showing sorting arrows, but with no effect when clicking sections. Calling `setQuery()` also makes `select()` invalid (it returns `False`, as `selectStatement()` returns a null string because it can't construct the select statement due to the missing table name). Truth is, `setTable()` already calls `setQuery()` on its own (using `selectStatement()`). So, while for general, basic usage `setQuery()` *might* be fine, it shouldn't be suggested (especially to beginners) as it could make it think that it's the standard accepted use, and is valid for *any* query.

Comment: It's then better to suggest (and, normally, use) the predefined behavior, and eventually specify that for specific select queries the QSqlQueryModel can be used instead (remembering that it's read only by default, and write support must be added by implementing `setData()` and `flags()`). Whenever in doubt, I strongly suggest to carefully study the sources; woboq provides a very good code browser, which has a really valid highlighting system that is incredibly helpful for studying and understanding: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqltablemodel.cpp.html

Comment: Code edited to use setTable by default.